# Print Specific Row in 2D Array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

How would I get just the second row to print in this 4x4 array?

```
double [][] table = new double[4][4];

for(int i = 0; i < table.length; i++){
 for(int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++)
  table[i][j] = (Math.random() * 10);
}
```

Comment: You want to print this array after storing the data?

Comment: Yes, but just what's stored in the second row

Comment: I know how to print the entire array, I'm just having problems with the logic on specifically getting just a specific row

Comment: Do you want just the fourth row or is it the fourth COLUMN you want?

Comment: I need to just print the row

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
for(int j = 0; j < table[1].length; j++)
   System.out.print(table[1][j]+" - ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
// table[0] == 1st row
// table[1] == 2nd row
// etc..

for(int i = 0; i < table[1].length; i++) 
    System.out.println(table[1][i]); // Print each item of the 2nd row
```

Comment: This did the trick. I just needed to remove the second for loop

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the usage, you may want to use a method to print a specific row. Something like this

```
public void printRow(int r){
    for(int i=0; i<table[r-1].length; i++){
        if(i>0){
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(table[r-1][i]);
    }
}
```

In this example, you would call `printRow(2);` when you want to print the 2nd row.